# How does the electric current in a MRI machine flow?

Tags: magnetic-fields

For a project, I was researching about the MRI machine, and I need to find how the electric current in a MRI machine flows.(like which direction, what shape, and how) I have tried google and wiki, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: do you mean the *electric* current or the magnetic *field*?

Comment: Have you tried Google? Wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_magnetic_resonance_imaging

Comment: Round and round in a superconducting coil...